# How to karma/jasmine test property in Angular service

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have an angular component (Purchases) that has the following code in the constructor

```
this.userAuthService.loggedInUser.subscribe(user => {
  this.taxName = user.TaxName || 'GST';
});
```

The UserAuthService has the following defined in it's constructor

```
private loggedInUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as User);
public loggedInUser = this.loggedInUserSubject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
```

I'm trying to write a unit test to ensure the Purchases component is created, but I'm getting the error

> "Failed:  : could not find an object to spy upon for loggedInUser()".

I'm fairly new to unit testing Angular, so I'm not sure if I have it set up properly, to begin with. Can anyone help with how I can test the constructor of the `PurchasesComponent`?

Here's the test for it:

```
describe('PurchasesComponent', () => {
    let component: PurchasesComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PurchasesComponent>;
    let service: UserAuthService;
    let mockData = {TaxName: 'GST'};

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        spyOn(service, 'loggedInUser').and.callFake(() => of(mockData));
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [PurchaseMadeComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: UserAuthService, useValue: {} }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PurchaseMadeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        service = TestBed.inject(UserAuthService);
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, it can't mock the `loggedInUser` Observable on something(`service` in this case) that's not defined yet.

Also, since this is a property on the `UserAuthService`, and you're mocking the whole service as a mock service, try mocking the `loggedInUser` property right inside the mock of the `UserAuthService`.

Something like this:

```
describe('PurchasesComponent', () => {
  let component: PurchasesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture < PurchasesComponent > ;
  let service: UserAuthService;
  
  const mockLoggedInUser = new BehaviorSubject<any>({ TaxName: 'GST' });
  const MockUserAuthService = {
    loggedInUser: mockLoggedInUser.asObservable()
  }

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [PurchaseMadeComponent],
      providers: [{
        provide: UserAuthService,
        useValue: MockUserAuthService,
      }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PurchaseMadeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    service = TestBed.inject(UserAuthService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thats solved the first error, but now it's telling me "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Comment: @CaptainMorgan try `spyOn(service, 'loggedInUser').and.returnValue(of(mockData));` instead

Comment: Still getting the same error "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" after changing to suggestion above